# Display collection of elements, hide active element

Tags: ember.js

**UPDATE** Since asking this question I have redesigned my UI such that I no longer need this feature; however I'm leaving this open and active for the sake of helping others who end up with a similar problem.

I'm listing a collection of elements inside a template and each element has a link that opens it up to the right of the list. When one is clicked, I want to hide just that element and show it again when another one is clicked. My current approach to doing this is to set an attribute (active) to true on the model. This feels wrong for three reasons:

1. This attribute is not actually part of the model's schema, it's just arbitrary; which makes it seem like a controller concern (see below for why that doesn't work)
2. I have to first set active to false on all models, forcing me to change another router's model, which may be good or bad, I'm not sure
3. In the recent PeepCode screencast he showed using `@each.{attribute}` to bind to an attributes in an array; this makes me feel like there must be something similar I could do (like `this.set("@each.active", false)`) to set them all in one fell swoop

I wanted to use a method on the controller but it doesn't seem I can pass arguments into functions in Handlebars if statements.

Here's the code I'm using to render the list:

```
  {{#each note in controller}}
    {{!v-- I was trying to do {{#if isCurrentNote note}} but that seems to be invalid handlebars}}
    {{#unless note.active}}
      <li class="sticky-list-item">
        {{view Ember.TextArea classNames="sticky-note" valueBinding="note.content"}}
        {{#linkTo note note classNames="sticky-permalink"}}
          ∞
        {{/linkTo}}
      </li>
    {{/unless}}
  {{/each}}
```

And here are the routes:

```
App.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  // v-- this is what I was trying to do, but couldn't pass note in the template
  isCurrentNote: function(note){ 
    return this.get("currentNote") == note;
  }.property("currentNote")
});

App.NoteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller,model){
    this.modelFor("notes").forEach(function(note){
      note.set("active", false);
    });
    model.set("active", true);
  }
});
```

Like I said, what I have works, but it feels wrong. Can anyone confirm my suspicion or help ease my soul a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking through the API docs, I just found `setEach` on `Ember.Array`. This helps quell concern #3, but #1 is still bugging me.

Answer (score 2):

to me this looks like something that should be done mostly by the `NotesView` with a `NotesController` that stores the *Note selection*

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/colymba/UMkUL/6/

the `NotesController` would hold all the notes and a record of the selected one:

```
App.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  selectedNote: null,
  selectNote: function(id){
     var note = this.get('content').findProperty('id', id);
     this.set('selectedNote', note);
  }
});
```

with the `NotesView`observing that selection and showing/hiding elements of the list accordingly

```
App.NotesView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:  'notes',
  refresh: function(){
    var view = this.$(),
        selection = this.get('controller.selectedNote');
    if (view) {
        view.find('li').show();
        if (selection) view.find('li.note_'+selection.id).hide();
    }
  }.observes('controller.selectedNote')
});
```

Here is the `Note` object and it's 2 templates (when in a list or displayed in full). The *ListView* handles the `click` event and passes the `id` to the `NotesController`.

```
App.Note = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: '',
  content: ''
});

App.NoteView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'note'
});

App.NoteListItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    templateName: 'noteListItem',
    classNameBindings: ['noteID'],
    noteID: function(){
        return 'note_' + this._context.id;
    }.property(),
    click: function(e){
        this.get('controller').selectNote(this._context.id);
    }
});
```

in the `NotesView` template everything is displayed and if there is a `selectedNote`, we display the `Note` again in full:

```
{{#each note in controller}}
  {{#with note}}
    {{view App.NoteListItemView}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}

{{#if selectedNote}}
  {{#with selectedNote}}
    {{view App.NoteView}}
  {{/with}}
{{/if}}
```

the `Routes` to put it together

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('notes', { path: "/notes" });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
  enter: function() {
    this.transitionTo('notes');
  }
});
App.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
        App.Note.create({id: 1, name: 'Milk', content: '15% fresh milk'}),
        App.Note.create({id: 2, name: 'Juice', content: 'Orange with pulp'}),
        App.Note.create({id: 3, name: 'Cereals', content: 'Kelloggs Froot Loops'}),
    ];
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('content', model);
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('notes', { outlet: 'content' });
  }
});
```

Comment: I like that this gets around setting an arbitrary attribute on the model. One problem with this solution is that I lose the route to /notes/:note_id. The whole purpose of showing the selected note is so I can permalink it and easily find it later. I think your solution could be adapted to still have the route, alas since asking this question I have redesigned in such a way that I no longer need this complexity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suppose if you have your route like _/notes/:note_id_ you could set the `selectedNote` property on the controller when de-serializing the URL and so you can keep the `linkTo` helper?